# How can we remove the leading and traling spaces from a string in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a `first.properties` file and I am reading that file, skipping the first 5 lines and creating a new file with the remaining lines of `first.properties`. This is working fine. But I am getting spaces for each line in the newly created file. I want to remove these spaces.

I have used the following piece of code:

```
@echo off
set new=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "skip=5" %%L in (first.properties) do (
echo %%L>>NewProjectsInfo.properties 
)
endlocal
pause
```

`first.properties` is as follows:

```
name=abcd
number=bcde
address=cdef
mobile=efgh
worklocation=ghij
```

Please help me out to remove the spaces.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the entries in `first.properties` (after line 6) have leading and/or trailing spaces? Because the lines you posted (only 5) have not. I'd be surprised if the code you have got mysteriously creates any spaces.

Comment: This is somewhat backwards compared to your question in that it adds characters, but may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021464/batch-file-to-add-characters-to-beginning-and-end-of-each-line-in-txt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space after `NewProjectsInfo.properties` in your code. if that is removed, it works as you expect.

It's sad, but looks like, batch interprets command as entire line & separates out the redirection part. In bash, for example, the command terminates at `>` symbol itself.

e.g. `echo hello >somefile.txt world` will put `hello world` in `somefile.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  There can be issues when numbers directly precede the >> characters.
You are not using ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION so I removed it too.

```
@echo off
set new=0
setlocal
for /F "skip=5 delims=" %%L in (first.properties) do (
>>NewProjectsInfo.properties echo %%L
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "skip=5 delims=" %%i IN (rltsf.txt) DO CALL :unpad %%i
)>output.txt

FC rltsf.txt output.txt
GOTO :eof

:unpad
ECHO %*
GOTO :eof
```

This approach seemst to work, but I fancy it may be a little sensitive to line-content. Easier to test if we have representative data...