# How do I prepend a string to each line in a text file using Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a long list where each line reads

```
p1 Title 1
p24 Title 2
p84 Title 3
...
```

I need each file to be prepended with a simple string, the initials of the book like so.

```
MB.p1 Title 1
MB.p24 Title 2
MB.p84 Title 3
...
```

I have tried the tips on [Batch file to add characters to beginning and end of each line in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021464/batch-file-to-add-characters-to-beginning-and-end-of-each-line-in-txt-file) and [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file#)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I found that the easiest way was to use a combination of the two links posted above:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in (input.txt) do (echo MB.%a) >> output.txt
```

Comment: Your answer is practically the same than the accepted answer of your first link: `for /f "tokens=*" %a in (input.txt) do (echo "%a">> output.txt)`, so IMHO you shouldn't wasted an SO question/answer just to post this "solution", specially if you already solved your problem _before_ posted the question...

Comment: Oh, I understand the reason now. _All_ [your 6 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2582691/paul-h?tab=answers) in this site are answers _to your own questions_! This is a strange way to accumulate activity and rep points...

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with answering your own question, but it better be a novel question and answer that makes a significant contribution to the SO collective knowledge base. As Aacini points out, this is nearly identical to the existing posted answers. Plus there are a gazillion existing Q&As regarding editing text files with batch. This Q&A offers nothing that has not already been covered.